# ssas partition error when build project - The item already exists in the collection

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, cube

I have created a new cube using SSAS 2013. When trying to build\rebuild the project, I'm getting this error - 'xxx.partitions' cannot be loaded: The item already exists in the collection. Does anyone knows what that's mean?
Deploy and process the cube works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete the SSAS database on the server and redeploy again, then it worked :)